# Crossbrowser XmlDsig

Tags: xml, cross-browser, xml-signature

I am building a web site where the user has to digitally sign a xml reciept to confirm that he recieved the package. I am currently doing this using a custom ActiveX control in IE. I was wondering if I could accomplish the same thing with/for other browsers. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no simple and free method for signing XML docs in web browser. We use XSign from [Lizard Labs](http://www.lizard-labs.net) in Internet Explorer and Firefox for signing XML documents on client side. The component is good enough, W3C compliant, stable and easy to use and install (doesn't require additional libraries and SDK). The version for Windows Mobile is also available but I don't have experience with it. You can download and try demo version.

Answer (score 1):

Doing cross-browser XML-DSig signature requires an alternative technology to Active/X (which will only run in MSIE) e.g. a Java applet.

We at [isigma](http://www.isigma.es) have developed our own applet-based solution, which we have successfully run on MSIE, Firefox, Chrome and Opera for Windows, plus also on Firefox for MAC and Linux (we tested on Ubuntu) - and probably Safari as well but I can't confirm this. There are several open-source and commercial applet-based solutions that will cover a much wider installed base than a pure Active/X solution.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little old, but I found recently a alternative that is worth trying: 
http://www.openoces.org/opensign/

It uses a Java Applet and is released in a LGPL license.

Answer (score 0):

Try [XML Signature Java Applet](http://www.digisecsolutions.com/index.html) for XML signatures in browsers. It works with all browsers that support Java on Windows and Linux, including Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just published a library that aims to make this possible, take a look: https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/xadesjs